# Auto-login, NTLM header seems to erase $_SESSION on redirect

Tags: php

I'm trying to create an auto login script. The computers are using IE8 on XP. The code successfully retrieves the user's Windows username and places it into a session, but once redirect is complete, the session is wiped clean.

In index.php:

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SERVER["AUTH_USER"]) || $_SERVER["AUTH_USER"] == '') {
      header('WWW-Authenticate: NTLM', false);
      exit;
}

# Extract username
$user = explode('\\',$_SERVER["AUTH_USER"]);
$_SESSION['username'] = strtolower($user[1]);
print_r($_SESSION); // Success!
header("Location: index2.php");
```

In index2.php:

```
session_start()
print_r($_SESSION); // Fail. array()
```

The key problem seems to be the header part because during testing, I've removed it and put in a dummy username and it successfully passes to the next page. I need the header though, because it is needed to do the NTLM authentication (ie. Put the AUTH_USER details in the $_SERVER array.)

EDIT
I turned off anonymous authentication in IIS, then removed the header part and all worked. However, this creates loads of other problems.

Comment: Are you `session_start()` ing each script?

Comment: Yes, in both. Otherwise the print_r($_SESSION) would always return empty.

Comment: Make sure the clients are accepting cookies and that the php session cookie is being set on the first page. Or pass the session id through GET.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to confirm the question posted and answered by Paul for anyone who gets stuck on this like I did.

I have multiple web sites running under IIS using PHP.  Works great.  Then I added a site that uses NTLM authenticated security (ie Windows Login).  The session built on page 1 was not being carried forward to page 2.  I dumped the `$_SERVER` settings, played with the INI file all to no eval.  I broke the application down to the bare bones basics like Paul and confirmed that it only happens when prompting for the authentication.

To reproduce, start a new browser window, login to page 1 using winodws authentication - do not click save password, click a link to go to page 2 - no session variable.  Close the browser and start again (to reset the authentication).  This time remove the authentication stuff from page 1 before surfing.  Goto page 2 and the session is there.

Turning off **"Enable anonymous access"** in the **"Directory Security/Authentication and access control"** property settings of my web site solved to problem.

Thanks Paul.

Answer (score 0):

Add `session_set_cookie_params(0)` prior to starting the session. IE8 has a problem handling non-persistent cookies.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this flaw in IE8 that I wasn't aware of. I tried the `session_set_cookie_params(0)` but it didn't work.